# Determining $ \frac{ F(a',b',c')}{ F(a,b,c)} $

Tags: geometry

Let be $abc$ a triangle and $$ a'= \lambda_1 a + \mu_1 b + \nu_1 c $$ $$ b'= \lambda_2 a + \mu_2 b + \nu_2 c $$ $$c'= \lambda_3 a + \mu_3 b + \nu_3 c $$

I want to show that that ( $F(a,b,c)$ - Area of the triangle)
$$ \frac{F(a',b',c')}{ F(a,b,c) } = \lvert det \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & \mu_1 & \nu_1 \\ \lambda_2 & \mu_2 & \nu_2 \\ \lambda_3 & \mu_3 & \nu_3\end{pmatrix} \rvert $$

So I have started by :

$$ det \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & \mu_1 & \nu_1 \\ \lambda_2 & \mu_2 & \nu_2 \\ \lambda_3 & \mu_3 & \nu_3\end{pmatrix}= \lambda_1 \mu_2 \nu_3+ \mu_1 \nu_2 \lambda_3+ \nu_1 \lambda_2 \mu_3- \lambda_3 \mu_2 \nu_1 - \mu_3 \nu_2 \lambda_1 - \nu_3 \lambda_2 \lambda_1 $$

Here I just don't get any further..
any help here very appreciated!

Comment: The formula you have is incorrect.

Comment: Oh really? What is the right formula then?..or what formular can I use

Comment: I don't think there is a formula for the area of the triangle as set up by your question, however, your formula as it is given applies to the volume of the parallelepiped formed by the three vectors $A, B, C$.

Comment: A slightly different formula for triangles that have a vertex at the origin, and two sides extending from the origin to $A$ and $B$ can be formulated using a $2 \times 2$ determinant.

Comment: Actually, if $\triangle A'B'C' $ is generated from $\triangle ABC$, using $ A' = M A , B' = M B, C' = M C $ then $ \dfrac{[A'B'C']}{[ABC]} =$ Absolute value of determinant of $M$, where $M$ here is a $2 \times 2 $ matrix.

Comment: What is $M$ exactly?